# HTML2CANVAS sent url via $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, html2canvas

I have rendered an image via html2canvas and jquery:

```
<script>
    function capture() {
        console.log("function is running");
        jQuery('#square').html2canvas({
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                var url;
                url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
                jQuery('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
                //Submit the form manually
                //var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                window.open(url);
                jQuery("#myForm").submit();
                console.log(jQuery('#img_val').val());
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

The code works all fine, and I see the image via the window.opne.

The issue I have is when I submit my form holding the image value is NOT passed. I know it's set because I see that via console.

My form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Take Screenshot Of Div" onclick="capture();" />
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/save.php" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>
```

My Save.php

```
<?php
//save.php code

//Show the image
var_dump($_POST['img_val']);
echo 'Billede:<br />';
echo '<img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';

//Get the base-64 string from data
$filteredData=substr($_POST['img_val'], strpos($_POST['img_val'], ",")+1);

//Decode the string
$unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);

//Save the image
file_put_contents('img' . rand(0,10000) . '.png', $unencodedData);
?>
```

Why is the value of the renderend image not passed via my form - when I know I set it via jQuery ?

Comment: It all looks good. If you are using Chrome, can you use the Networking pane in the Web developer tools to see if the info is being sent? This way you can determine wether it's never sent or maybe lost somewhere by the server.

Comment: `echo '<img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />';` show image?

Comment: No <img src="'.$_POST['img_val'].'" />  does not show the image.